# change date formating using Application_BeginRequest method

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime, date-format

i want to change date time format for all the system using Application_BeginRequest method.
now i'm using this method

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;

    }
```

i think it should display the datetime formate like this "03/11/2013 01:59 AM" but actually it is appear like this "03/11/2013 01:59 AM 1:59:03 AM". so what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and i'm using the following method

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();


        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "hh:mm tt";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;

    }
```